# How to get an object property from another object? Firebase + vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have few objects in my Firebase: `user`, `attributes` and `attributesValues`.

`User` has a property called `attributes`, its values are in the `attributes` object.

So if object `user` looks like this:

```
"user': {
    "name": "John"
    "attributes": {
        "0": "2",
    }
}
```

and `attributes` object looks like this:

```
"attributes": {
    "id": "0",
    "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

`attributesValues` object looks like this:

```
"attributesValues": [
    "valueOne|valueTwo|valueThree|valueFour|valueFive",
     "typeOne|typeTwo|typeThree|typeFour|typeFive",
     "numberOne|numberTwo|numberThree|numberFour|numberFive",
     "addressOne|addressTwo|addressThree|addressFour|addressFive"
    ]}
```

How do I display the lastName of the user? `user.attributes.[0]` does not work.

This is my firebase file:
    import { initializeApp } from 'firebase'

```
const app = initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'apiKey',
    authDomain: 'projectId.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://projectId.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'projectId',
    storageBucket: '',
    messagingSenderId: 'messagingId',
    appId: 'appId'
})

export const db = app.database()
export const usersRed = db.ref('users')
export const attributesRef = db.ref('attributes')
export const attributesValuesRef = db.ref('attributesValues')
```

Comment: So what is the `"0": "2"` in `user.attributes` referring to?

Comment: It's `user.attributes['0']` (since the `'0'` is a key here, not an array index. `0` might work, you need to get rid of the `.` though). This will yield `"2"`, so how do you get from there to the attribute object's "Doe"? In general, documents in collections can reference other documents, and you can instruct the DB to auto-populate the references with the actual documents.

Comment: Why don't you just save the last name with the user? This looks really overly complicated.

Comment: @jb31 `user.attributes` key refers to 0 index in `attributes` object. `2` refers to 2 index in `attributesValues` object
@ChrisG but how do I do that?
@AndréKool those objects are a little more complicated than that, that's how my firebase database is constructed and I can't change it.

Comment: @Atreyu And what does `attributesValues` look like? Is it `Object.values(attributes)`?

Comment: It's another Firebase collection, I've added it to main post

Comment: @Jb31 any ideas?